# unable to install and configure chef-server on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, configuration, failover, chef

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed on aws cloud and I am trying to install chef server on it, but it does not configures correctly and returns an error. I am following this simple guide for installation [here](http://thornelabs.net/2013/09/16/install-the-open-source-chef-server-setup-knife-on-your-workstation-and-bootstrap-your-first-client-server.html)

And I get the following error after running sudo sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure

how to pass this error and configure chef server ?

```
execute[/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef] action run Error executing action run on resource 'execute[/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef]'

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed

Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1' ---- Begin output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef ---- STDOUT: STDERR: createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"? ---- End output of /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef ---- Ran /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef returned 1

Resource Declaration:

In /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/postgresql.rb

141: execute "/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef" do 142: user node['chef_server']['postgresql']['username'] 143: not_if database_exists 144: retries 30 145: notifies :run, "execute[migrate_database]", :immediately 146: end 147:

Compiled Resource:

Declared in /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/postgresql.rb:141:in `from_file'

execute("/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef") do action "run" retries 0 retry_delay 2 command "/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/createdb -T template0 -E UTF-8 opscode_chef" backup 5 returns 0 user "opscode-pgsql" cookbook_name :"chef-server" recipe_name "postgresql" not_if "/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/chpst -u opscode-pgsql /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/psql -d 'template1' -c 'select datname from pg_database' -x|grep opscode_chef" end

[2014-12-02T06:57:49+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers [2014-12-02T06:57:49+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete [2014-12-02T06:57:49+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out Chef Client failed. 49 resources updated [2014-12-02T06:57:49+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the hint from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735878/chef-server-ctl-reconfigure-fails-after-customizing-the-postgresql-port. There is already an installed PostgreSQL. The fix is as follows.

> Modify existing PostgreSQL installation's port number to be 5433 and
>   let Chef's instance use 5432. Now the "chef-server-ctl reconfigure"
>   command completes successfully.

It is also possible to change the port that Chef Server is using to access PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hey Thanks :) it worked I changed the postgres port to 5433 and it worked

Comment: Feel free to choose my answer or I can incorporate if you have improvements. :)